# MySQL triggers syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

```
CREATE TABLE reservation(
    reserv_id int,
    reserv_date numeric(8,0),
    start_date numeric(8,0) NOT NULL,
    end_date numeric(8,0) NOT NULL,
    payment ENUM('Cash','Credit Card','Check'),
    PRIMARY KEY(reserv_id),
    CHECK (reserv_date<start_date),
    CHECK (start_date<end_date)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;


delimiter //
create trigger date_check
before insert on reservation
for each row
begin
   IF ((new.reserv_date > new.start_date) or (new.start_date > new.end_date)) THEN SIGNAL 'error message';
   END IF;
end;//
delimiter ;
```

I am trying to create this trigger in MySQL but it keeps throwing me the following error:

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''error message';
  END IF;
end' at line 5

What is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IF ((new.reserv_date > new.start_date) or (new.start_date > new.end_date)) THEN 
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' 
    SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'error message';
```

Read the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/signal.html) for more details.